# query not executing properly on php but does so on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML page through which I will be getting user input. I am taking those values and performing a query on my mysql database. This is my PHP code which does so.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";


$A = $_POST['A'];
$B = strtoupper($_POST['B']);
$C = $_POST['C'];
$D = $_POST['D'];
$E = $_POST['E'];
$F = $_POST['F'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=yyyy;dbname=' . $A, $username, $password);
    echo "Connected Successfully <br>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "ERROR! : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$query = "call query(?,?,?,?,?,1,'filename.txt')";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($B, $C, $D, $E, $F));
?>
```

This code throws no errors, but the script is not doing the job it's supposed to do. If I go into the mysql database and perform the query

> call query(r_value,r_value,r_value,r_value,r_value,1,'filename.txt') ;

it creates a file with the filename and does the writing job perfectly. Using PHP the same result is not being achieved, but I am not seeing any errors thrown as well.

The job of this query procedure is to perform some queries based on input and write the results onto an output file whose location is passed as a parameter.
Thanks in advance

Note: I also tried adding ';' in the $query but it made no difference.

edit:
when i am using simple query instead of prepared statements it seems to work but i am not willing to use simple statements because of SQL injection

Comment: note: question mark placeholders doesn't need quotes

Comment: also make sure your DB user has the correct permissions to use stored procedures.

Comment: Yes you have probably not the permissions on writting.

Comment: Show what `$stmt->errorInfo()` returns after failed execution.

Comment: execution did not fail , thats the problem. i have grant all on the user so execute permissions should not be a problem @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: errorInfo() returns nothing @AlekseyRatnikov

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's related or not but I had a few problems like this in the past and the answer was a different timezone while working with DB directly or through PHP. As a result, select statement returned something in one case and nothing in another for select statements based on conditions with date/time.

Comment: i am working with date/time but timezones shouldn't be an issue i guess. anyways how did you deal with your problem ? @ConstantineUA

Comment: I specified the necessary timezone while instantiatin a PDO-object: array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET time_zone = \'+03:00\'') as a last parameter

Comment: @ConstantineUA didn't help right now , but this was something new , so thanks for that :)

Comment: Probably it isn't the case when you have web-server and database on the same machine but we had on different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a designing mistake , input user format was different from the format that was needed making the script to fail. sorry for this mistake and if i wasted your time.